# Building Solr indexes through Haystack throws unknown field error

Tags: solr, django-haystack

I'm trying to integrate Haystack with Solr. When I try to build the index, I get an error
"Unknown  field django_id" from SOLR. What's causing this to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schema.xml was malformed as I had copied additional text from the console.

Answer (score 12):

You also get this error if you haven't given Solr the schema.xml file which Haystack generates for you, as explained here in the docs.

[django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#reindex](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#reindex)

Comment: that's me! I forgot to copy the schema.xml :)

Comment: After I placed my schema in the conf dir, I had to restart solr to get it to work. BTW, the conf dir is apache-solr-3.5.0/example/solr/conf.

Comment: restarting solr was key for me, i tried different versions of haystack and a bunch of wierd ass configurations to no avail. one restart and everything started working. ::facepalm::

Comment: the link above does not work anymore this one is up to date: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#reindex

Answer (score 1):

If you added new fields to your database and [copied the generated XML files](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/tutorial.html#reindex) from Haystack, you might also be getting this error because you haven't restarted jetty/Tomcat/whatever server you are using. This solved it for me on Ubuntu and **Jetty**:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/jetty stop
sudo /etc/init.d/jetty start
```

(by the way, that would also be the same as simply doing this):

```
sudo service jetty restart
```

Or, if you are using **tomcat**, that would be

```
sudo service tomcat6 restart
```

Edit: (tested this with Tomcat, and it solved the same problem again, the same as with Jetty).